# Use Deepl API and google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working on a script to translate a text included in a google sheets cell with the deepl api. My code works and generates a result, but it does not recognise the text included in the cell.

This is the code I am using:

```
function deeplapi() {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.deepl.com/v2/translate?auth_key=xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx&text="+ text +"&target_lang=en&source_lang=es");

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var text = sheet.getRange(3,2).getValue();

var json = response.getContentText(); 

var data = JSON.parse(json); 
Logger.log(data);
}
```

Although it generates a response, the text entered appears as "undefined".I don't know why this is happening.

Here is the image of my sheet and the result of the script.

The result is this. As you can see, the text appears as undefined:

*Información    {translations=[{text=undefined, detected_source_language=ES}]}*

[image: sheet]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define `text` **before** `response` since `text` is used in the argument inside the `fetch` function:

```
function deeplapi() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var text = sheet.getRange(3,2).getValue(); // define text before response
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.deepl.com/v2/translate?auth_key=xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx&text="+ text +"&target_lang=en&source_lang=es");
  var json = response.getContentText(); 
  var data = JSON.parse(json); 
  Logger.log(data);
}
```

Comment: Sorry to ask you again! Do you know how I can print the translation result on a sheet?

Comment: What is your data object?  Could you please ask a new question regarding that so you can provide clear view of the the `data` input? @Folleloide

Comment: I have added a question with the above. Thanks for your help! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66305817/how-to-print-the-result-of-a-script-on-the-current-sheet

Answer (score 1):

I've found [Translate with DeepL](https://www.translate.rocks/) on the addon store.

It adds a DEEPL formula to Google Sheets like:

```
= DEEPL("Hey there", "es", "en")
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers did not work for me.

```html
function DEEPL(text, sourceLang, targetLang) {
    if (text == "") {
      return "";
    }
  
    var requestOptions = { 
      "method" : "post",
      "headers" : {
         "Authorization" : "DeepL-Auth-Key AUTH_KEY_HERE",
       },
       "payload": {
          "text": text,
          "source_lang": sourceLang,
          "target_lang": targetLang
       }
    }
  
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api-free.deepl.com/v2/translate", requestOptions);
    
    var json = response.getContentText();
    var data = JSON.parse(json);
    return data["translations"][0]["text"];
  }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).